# Associative arrays in HTML forms using WordPress post meta data functions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, associative-array

I have a collection of objects that need to be saved/retrieved in wp_postmeta table of a custom post type.

**Example structure:**

```
array(
    array( 
        'firstname'   => 'Johnny',
        'middlename'  => 'William'
    ),
    array( 
        'firstname'   => 'Jane',
        'middlename'  => 'Alice'
    )
)
```

I would like to be able to iterate through the objects like this:

```
$children = get_post_meta( $postid, '_children', true);

$arrlength = count($children);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
{
    echo '<input type="text" name="_children[][firstname]" id="_children[][firstname]" value="' . $meta_values['_children'][0][$x][firstname] . '" /><br />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_children[][middlename]" id="_children[][middlename]" value="' . $meta_values['children'][0][$x][middlename] . '" /><br />';
}
```

I don't think the above is correct. I'm trying to get the posted data saved in `save_post` action with:

```
function test_meta_save( $post_id ) {

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ '_children_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ '_children_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }
    if( isset( $_POST[ '_children' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_children', array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST[ '_children' ] );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'test_meta_save' );
```

I know the above isn't correct either.

Comment: Please try `$meta_values['_children'][$x][firstname]` just remove `[0]` !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I wondered about that [0]. The database shows NULL for the value, so I'm thinking there is a problem in the `post_save` line of code I posted.

Comment: Is `$_POST[ '_children' ]` an array ? How do you enter the initial values !

Comment: They are submitted from the form in the loop example above. Yes, it would be an `array( 'firstname' => 'Johnny', 'middlename' => 'William'),...`

Comment: How is this possible ? To show the form you need the values ! and to have the values you need to show the form :D !

Comment: The form is output in the `for` loop. There are text fields. The values get entered and the form is submitted.

Comment: Yes, to output the form in `for` loop,  you must have some values in the DB ! Am I getting something wrong ?

Comment: Initially the form fields are blank, sure. Then I fill them in with some random data and click the submit button. Why does there need to be data in the DB for that? It's an HTTP post and now I want to save the posted form variables to the DBs postmeta. Theoretically, yes, these values would be displayed in the form next time it is loaded.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I edited my question to show more of the code in question. I think it will make more sense to you?

Comment: Yes! I think your code to save the `post_meta ` is correct ! But in your form  you need to change `name="_children[][firstname]"` to `name="_children['. $x.'][firstname]"` and `name="_children[][middlename]"` to `name="_children['.$x.'][middlename]"` to save the `middlename` and `firstname ` in the same array !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I made the changes to the form's name attributes. They all render with index values now, but the postmeta for _children is being saved as `a:1:{i:1;s:5:"Array";}` - I still think there's something wrong with the way I'm saving it in my code above, but I'm not sure how associative arrays are suppose to be saved from a form to postmeta. I know this must be explained someplace... I'm just not finding it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here you have the same problem that in your last question but this time with [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) where last argument should be **`false`**. because you are **reading/creating** **`arrays`** values and **NOT `strings`** values.

In your code:

```
$children = get_post_meta( $postid, '_children', true);
```

You need to remove last argument in  your [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function, as default value is **`false`**.
Instead you will have:

```
$children = get_post_meta( $postid, '_children');

$arrlength = count($children);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
{
    echo '<input type="text" name="_children[][firstname]" id="_children[][firstname]" value="' . $meta_values['_children'][0][$x][firstname] . '" /><br />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_children[][middlename]" id="_children[][middlename]" value="' . $meta_values['children'][0][$x][middlename] . '" /><br />';
}
```

---

References:

- [WordPress Code Reference - add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/)
- [WordPress Code Reference - update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)
- [WordPress Code Reference - get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: I see in your `for` loop that you specify an extra dimension. The `[0]` dimension you reference is an effect of setting get_post_meta() last argument to false? Thank you for the explanation and references.